# Ruby Net/SSH - Launch remote Python script and detach

Tags: python, ruby, ssh

I need to launch a remote Python script through SSH. The Python script on the remote machine needs to perform some file manipulation, launch an executable for a simulation (from a few hours to days), collect the results and write to a file.

I am launching the script from Ruby using `Net-SSH exec!`. I use channels to capture `STDERR` and `STDOUT`.

The script works fine, but now I would like to detach the running script on the remote machine from my local Ruby script. I will then check directly on the remote machine the state of the simulation.

I have tried to run the script using `nohup`.

```
Net::SSH.exec!("nohup python script.py args > out.log 2> err.log < /dev/null &")
```

The script is detached and I get back control immediately, but the script on the remote machine gets killed and I cannot find the process in background.

Ideally I would launch the simulation executable directly from Ruby, but I have to use Python because I need some libraries that are not available in Ruby.

Is the approach above correct? Can I use `nohup` with Net-SSH?

Is there a better approach?

EDIT:

```
  def self.ssh_exec!(ssh, cmd, log = nil)

    ssh.open_channel do |ch|

      ch.request_pty do |chan,success|
      end

      ch.exec(cmd) do |chan, success|
        raise "could not execute command" unless success

        # "on_data" is called when the process writes something to stdout
        chan.on_data do |c, data|
          log ? (log << data) : (puts data) 
        end

        # "on_extended_data" is called when the process writes something to stderr
        chan.on_extended_data do |c, type, data|
          log ? (log.error data) : (puts data) 
        end

        chan.on_close do
           puts 'Done'
        end
      end
    end    
   end
```

then I call

```
  Net::SSH.start(aws_ip, user, options = aws_options) do |ssh|

    script = File.join(path, 'pyfoam_scripts', 'run_case.py')
    cmd = "source...; python #{script} #{dst_case}"
    RG::Utils.ssh_exec!(ssh, cmd, @logger)

    ssh.loop
  end
```

where

```
:options => {:keys => path_to_key, 'key.pem'), 
                        :keepalive => true,
                        :timeout => 3000, 
                        :compression => true,
                        :compression_level => 6},
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post more of the code that creates the ssh connection; in particular I wonder if you're allocating a PTY for the session that launches the script. That said, I don't see anything wrong with that one line of code that you posted. You should try to figure out exactly what is happening to the script that causes it to exit. Is it getting a signal? Is it encountering some other problem and deciding on its own to exit?

Comment: Let me redirect you to [unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261631) which I think you could find useful.
IMHO from what I see there is not a problem with the Net::SSH on your side.

Comment: I have added an extract of my code

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more testing and thanks to the comments I realised that there were three errors in my code:

1. I was using `channels`. `Channels` are used to establish a communication with the remote machine, capture the output, use callbacks. In this case, I didn't need any of this.
2. `Net::SSH.exec!` waits for the command to complete. I needed to launch and forget. (Silly mistake)
3. `ssh.loop` is not needed. See 1.

After fixing the errors above, it works like a charm.